# All possible dates between two dates with 60 minutes interval or variable interval

Tags: php

I need some improvement ideas for my appointment system.

I have this mysql query result which means free interval time:

```
hours        freeend
09:00:00     12:00:01
14:00:00     15:00:01
16:00:00     19:00:01
```

and time interval, let's say 120 minutes. ( stored in variable $d )

This is my php code for display free interval time but it is not 100% correct...

```
$d = 120; // let's say
$nr = $result->num_rows;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$start    = new DateTime($row['hours']);
$end      = new DateTime($row['freeend']); // add 1 second because last one is not included in the loop

if ($nr < 2) {$interval = new DateInterval('PT60M');} else {$interval = new DateInterval('PT'.$d.'M');}


$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$previous = '';
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $current = $dt->format("H:i");
    if (!empty($previous)) {

        echo "<label class='btn btn-secondary bhours btn-lg'><input type='radio' name='hours' value='{$previous}' id='{$previous}'>{$previous}</label>";
    }
    $previous = $current;
}

}
```

It returns only 2 results:

```
09:00
16:00
```

Correct would be:

```
09:00
10:00
16:00
17:00
```

Any ideas of how to implement?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you let me know what is that you want to achieve after retrieving results from DB? Also, the `if($nr < 2)` can come before the while loop itself.

Comment: Hours and freeend means free interval time for any appointment. So if we take first row: 09-12 (3 hours) and we do want to make a new '120' minutes appointment then  we could possibly have two free interval times between 9-12: 9-11 and 10-12

Comment: Ok, so for `14:00:00-15:00:01` there can't be any 2 hours appointment we can fix and for `16:00:00-19:00:01`, we can have `16-18`,`17-19`? Can we not have `16:30-18:30`? Also, is `120` minutes fixed , or it can also be `60` minutes?

Comment: Exactly! This is what I want! I do have only rounded dates

Comment: I have added my answer.

Comment: I've seen it. Thank you very much but I can t verify right now. I come back later with some news. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 


$arr = [
            [
                'hours' => '09:00:00',
                'freeend' => '12:00:01'
            ],
            [
                'hours' => '14:00:00',
                'freeend' => '15:00:01'
            ],
            [
                'hours' => '16:00:00',
                'freeend' => '19:00:01'
            ],
            [
                'hours' => '10:00:00',
                'freeend' => '23:00:01'
            ]
        ];

$appointment_duration = new DateInterval('PT2H');
$next_hour = new DateInterval('PT1H');

foreach($arr as $row){
    $start_time = new DateTime($row['hours']);
    $end_time   = new DateTime($row['freeend']);

    echo "Appointments available between $row[hours] and $row[freeend] <br/>";

    $curr_start_time = $start_time;
    $curr_end_time   = new DateTime($start_time->format("H:i:s"));
    $curr_end_time   = $curr_end_time->add($appointment_duration);

    do{
        if($curr_end_time > $end_time){
            echo "$row[hours]-$row[freeend] <br/>";
            break;
        }

        echo $curr_start_time->format("H:i:s"),"-",$curr_end_time->format("H:i:s"),"<br/>";
        $curr_start_time = $curr_start_time->add($next_hour);
        $curr_end_time   = new DateTime($curr_start_time->format("H:i:s"));
        $curr_end_time   = $curr_end_time->add($appointment_duration);

    }while($curr_end_time <= $end_time);    

    echo "<br/>";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Appointments available between 09:00:00 and 12:00:01 
09:00:00-11:00:00
10:00:00-12:00:00

Appointments available between 14:00:00 and 15:00:01 
14:00:00-15:00:01 

Appointments available between 16:00:00 and 19:00:01 
16:00:00-18:00:00
17:00:00-19:00:00

Appointments available between 10:00:00 and 23:00:01 
10:00:00-12:00:00
11:00:00-13:00:00
12:00:00-14:00:00
13:00:00-15:00:00
14:00:00-16:00:00
15:00:00-17:00:00
16:00:00-18:00:00
17:00:00-19:00:00
18:00:00-20:00:00
19:00:00-21:00:00
20:00:00-22:00:00
21:00:00-23:00:00
```

Comment: Thank your very much for your help! It's working correctly now. Big step for my project. Thanks again !

Comment: Glad it helped :)